# Bash escaping and syntax

Tags: bash

I have a small bash file which I intend to use to determine my current ping vs my average ping.

```
#!/bin/bash
output=($(ping -qc 1 google.com | tail -n 1))
echo "`cut -d/ -f1 <<< "${output[3]}"`-20" | bc
```

This outputs my ping - 20 ms, which is the number I want. However, I also want to prepend a `+` if the number is positive and append "ms".

This brings me to my overarching problem: Bash syntax regarding escaping and such heavy "indenting" is kind of flaky.

While I'll be satisfied with an answer of how to do what I wanted, I'd like a link to, or explanation of how exactly bash syntax works dealing with this sort of thing.

Comment: What should happen if the number is not positive?

Comment: Then it will have a `-` sign from the bc output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
output=($(ping -qc 1 google.com | tail -n 1))
echo "${output[3]}" | awk -F/ '{printf "%+fms\n", $1-20}'
```

The `+` modifier in `printf` tells it to print the sign, whether it's positive or negative.

And since we're using `awk`, there's no need to use `cut` or `bc` to get a field or do arithmetic.

Answer (score 0):

Bash cannot handle floating point numbers. A workaround is to use `awk` like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
output=($(ping -qc 1 google.com | tail -n 1))
echo "`cut -d/ -f1 <<< "${output[3]}"`-20" | bc | awk '{if ($1 >= 0) printf "+%fms\n", $1; else printf "%fms\n", $1}'
```

*Note that this does not print anything if the result of bc is not positive*

Output:

```
$ ./testping.sh 
+18.209000ms
```

Comment: That doesn't print the result if it's negative.

Comment: @Barmar how can the result of ping be negative?

Comment: After subtracting 20 it can.

Comment: OP did not specify what should happen then

Answer (score 0):

Escaping is pretty awful in bash if you use the deprecated `` `..` `` style command expansion.   In this case, you have to escape any backticks, which means you also have to escape any other escapes. `$(..)` nests a lot better, since it doesn't add another layer of escaping.

In any case, I'd just do it directly:

```
ping -qc 1 google.com.org | awk -F'[=/ ]+' '{n=$6} 
    END { v=(n-20); if(v>0) printf("+"); print v}'
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my take on it, recognizing that the result from bc can be treated as a string:

```
output=($(ping -qc 1 google.com | tail -n 1))
output=$(echo "`cut -d/ -f1 <<< "${output[3]}"`-20" | bc)' ms'
[[ "$output" != -* ]] && output="+$output"
echo "$output"
```